# Cannot destroy bootstrap modal data

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

- jQuery 1.11.2
- Bootstrap 3.1.1

Here's how I'm building the modal:

```
    function fillModal(url, callback) {
        $(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#modal', function(){
            $('#modal').find('.modal-content').load(url, function() {
                callback();
            });
        });
    }
```

Here's how I'm attempting to destroy it.

```
   $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#modal', function (e) {
        $('#modal').find('.modal-content').empty();
        $(this).find('.modal-content').empty();
        $(e.target).find('.modal-content').empty();
        $('#modal').data('modal', null);
        $('#modal').data('bs.modal', null);
        $('#modal').removeData('bs.modal');
        $('#modal').removeData('modal');
        $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
        $(this).data('modal', null);
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
        $(this).removeData('modal');
        $(e.target).data('modal', null);
        $(e.target).data('bs.modal', null);
        $(e.target).removeData('bs.modal');
        $(e.target).removeData('modal');
    });
```

The above call fires, and I have tried *EVERYTHING* to actually blow away the bootstrap cached data, and it simply will not work. I've tried each one of those individually, I've tried them all together, I've tried destroying the entire modal HTML and re-adding it.

Nothing works - the contents of the modal are always old by two or three requests, sometimes the contents will revert to a very old request. Sometimes they'll be correct. Sometimes they'll be correct for a split second, and then get overwritten by the cached data....

I have no idea what's wrong.

Is there a setting I can apply like "dontKeep" or "noCache" or something when constructing the modal?

Comment: Can create stacksnippets http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when you call `shown.bs.modal`, it appends your callback to a stack each time it's called, rather than replacing what's there. So the first time I click, it adds the callback. The second time I click, it appends a new callback to the first one, the third time I click, it appends a third etc...

Those callbacks then render the contents in the order they happen to finish, so that's why the contents can seemingly appear randomly.

I resolved this issue by simply not attaching the modal contents populating behavior to the `shown.bs.modal` event, and simply calling it immediately upon click.